# HTML not resizing

Tags: css, html

I am currently working on my business website.  I am using ready made HTML code provided from a 3rd party for the front page.  The output is small and can not be resized.  On the 3rd party sites it shows me the html output is larger in size and has no scroll on the side.  I tried the appearance layout and no option for resize. I disabled many plugins and still nothing. I changed out theme and still same output.  I don't know if the issue lies with code below or CSS.  Any help would be greatly appreciated or steered in the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't have enough recommendation to comment your question and ask for more information.

To answer your question as I understand it :
This is CSS related.

If you only used the HTML part of your "3rd party site", it is normal you don't have any CSS style applied (unless it is inline CSS, but it's not the case here).

I recommend taking basic [CSS lessons](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) before anything else.

What you need is to style your `<select>` element, as in this exemple :

```
select.your-select-class{
    width : 8O%;
}
```

I don't know what you want your select to look like, so my answer can't be more specific.